# by + the + noun

Tags: nouns

1. He's well off. He can spend £ 1000 by (to?) the minute
2. You can buy cheese by (to?) the kilogramme.

Do these sound correct? Meaning every minute / kilogramme.

Answer (score 1):

If you really mean:

> He can spend £1000 *every* minute

i.e. £2000 in 2 minutes & £3000 in 3 minutes
then you want either of:

> He can spend £1000 *per* minute
>   He can spend £1000 *a* minute

Neither "by the minute" nor "to the minute" make sense in this context, but might be used in other contexts.

I'm unclear about your second question: I don't see how it can mean "every kilogram".
I assume that you mean you buy cheese by weight and that the unit of weight used is the kilogram, in which case the correct form would be:

> You can buy cheese *by* the kilogram.

The usage of "to the kilogram" does not make sense in this context, but could may sense in an example such as:

> On average, you get 5 bananas *to* the kilogram.

That means that, if you buy a kilogram of bananas, on average you would get 5 bananas.

As regards spelling, note that the Oxford Dictionaries ([ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/kilogram?q=kilogram)) state:

> **Kilogram** can also be spelled **kilogramme**; both are correct, although **kilogram** is far more common.

Since you are using "£" in your question, I assume you are writing from (or referring to) the UK. The normal spelling used within the UK is *kilogram*.

Comment: In the second example, the word *by* means *as measured in*. The problem with the first one is that the phrase *by the* can sometimes mean *every* - "He got sicker *by the* minute." Preposition use is very idiomatic with numerous patterns and exceptions.